# How to document fields and properties in Python?

Tags: python, documentation

It's easy to document a class or method in Python:

```
class Something:
  """ Description of the class. """

  def do_it(self):
    """ Description of the method. """
    pass

  class_variable = 1 # How to comment?

  @property
  def give_me_some_special_dict(self):
    """ doesn't work! Doc of general dict will be shown. """
    return {}
```

But how to document a field or property for usage in API docs or `help`?

Comment: This has been brought forward in the past. In "Abandoned, Withdrawn, and Rejected PEPs": http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0224/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the right way to put a docstring on Python property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16025462/what-is-the-right-way-to-put-a-docstring-on-python-property)

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Python has a PEP ([257](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring)) that defines Docstring Conventions. Regarding documentation of attributes, it states:

> String literals occurring immediately
>   after a simple assignment at the top
>   level of a module, class, or `__init__`
>   method are called "attribute
>   docstrings".

So the following are considered documented attributes:

```
class Foo(object):
  velocity = 1  
  """Foo's initial velocity - class variable"""

  def __init__(self, args):
    self.location = 0.0 
    """Foo's initial location - instance variable"""
```

(Edit: Fixed second docstring)

Comment: I was wondering too, [and Sphinx does](https://web.archive.org/web/20121017075218/http://sphinx.pocoo.org/ext/autodoc.html).

Comment: @Jochen: that's great, since Sphinx is the de-facto tool for Python documentation these days

Comment: Here's the PEP ([224](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0224/)) that talks about attribute docstrings.

Comment: Late comment but seems important to me: the standard library `help` function does not display attribute docstrings.

Comment: `help` does not show this documentation for "attribute docstrings" because they're not retained at runtime. According to [PEP 257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/): "They are not recognized by the Python bytecode compiler and are not accessible as runtime object attributes (i.e. not assigned to `__doc__`)"

Comment: @JosieThompson PEP 224 was *rejected* back in 2001. PEP 257 is the correct one to refer to.

Answer (score 14):

Documentation of a property in the python interpreter using help works fine for me, see [proprerty documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property). *Note: IPython's magic help operator, `?`, did **not** display the property docstring.*

```
>>> class foo(object):
>>>    def __init__(self, bar):
>>>        self._bar = bar
>>>    @property
>>>    def bar(self):
>>>        """bar property"""
>>>        return self._bar
>>> help(foo.bar)
Help on property:

    bar property
```

In Sphinx you must use the `:members:` directive to document properties, see [autodoc documentation](http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/autodoc.html). Works like a charm for me!

Attributes will also be documented by Sphinx if `:members:` is used. Docstrings for attributes can be given as comments preceding the attribute, but using a colon following the hash mark, EG `#: the foo attribute`. From the Sphinx autodoc documentation:

> For module data members and class attributes, documentation can either be put into a comment with special formatting (using a #: to start the comment instead of just #), or in a docstring after the definition. Comments need to be either on a line of their own before the definition, or immediately after the assignment on the same line. The latter form is restricted to one line only.

Answer (score 5):

Document freely accessible attributes in the class docstring or make them into properties. You're documenting properties properly, the problem might be in 2.x and old-style classes, which don't support descriptors — inherit from `object` in that case.

Answer (score 1):

With [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/) notation / [Restructured Text](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html) in your docstrings you can generate nicely formatted documentation from you Python sources automatically. It also supports arguments and return values for functions - no fields as far as I know, but you can easily create a list for them.