# How to get docstring of class variable

Tags: python

Consider the following code

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        """This comment is visible"""
        pass
    
    variable = True
    """This is not visible"""
```

Then the output for `help(A)` is:

```
Help on class A in module __main__:
class A(builtins.object)
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __init__(self)
 |      This comment is visible
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data descriptors defined here:
 |  
 |  __dict__
 |      dictionary for instance variables (if defined)
 |  
 |  __weakref__
 |      list of weak references to the object (if defined)
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data and other attributes defined here:
 |  
 |  variable = True
```

Further the docstring for the init function can be obtained with `help(A.__init__)`, but not for the `A.variable`. Is there any way to obtain the docstring for class variables?

Comment: Per https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring "attribute docstrings" are **not** exposed at runtime.

Comment: You might have to explore the AST. It's not very difficult but it takes a little time to get used to it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820276/docstring-for-variable here ya go

Answer (score -1):

Python does not provide this option, but you can use

1. typing.Annotated
2. [epydock](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/manual-docstring.html#variable-docstrings)