# How do I add descriptions to class variables in Python?

Tags: python, class, visual-studio-code, type-hinting

I am writing a *class* in Python, that I will import in several different scripts, to perform a specific task.

When I hover over the *class* or *class functions*, I can view the  '''*description*''' that I added. However, when I hover over a *class variable* I only get the *type hint* that I added.

In the *__init__()* I introduce the class variables and I've written a little *#comment* above each of them, so that I can always come back and identify their specific purpose. However, it would be much easier for debugging purposes to simply hover over the *class variable* in the code, and then see the description of that variable.

**How would I go about implementing that?**

I'll append a [screenshot of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTzX5.png), that I am writing in *VScode*, so that you can see what I mean about a '''*description*''' appearing when I hover over the *class* or a *class function*.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There aren't any class variables in that code, only instance attributes. Have you tried sphinx-style ``#:`` comments (note the colon)? Do the ``'''``-style "comments" work for your purpose?

Comment: `'''` comments *below* the attribute are usually supported…

Comment: You can use `typing.Annotated` See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8820636