# Document variable in python

Tags: javascript, python

If in the middle of my software, i have this variable that i need explain what it is and what is used for, i need document the variable.

I have a background in JS, so that's how i do:

```
/**
 * Explain what the variable is, and what is for.
 * @variable {Object} nameOfVariable
 */
var nameOfVariable = []
```

In the case of python:

```
# ??
name_of_variable = []
```

Is there conventions for this type of thing?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: From my experience, I usually document a function with docstrings, but if you are looking to document a variable, you could use the `#` in row succession until you have it documented. I would refer to https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#comments

Comment: http://effbot.org/zone/pythondoc.htm

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is - this is what I can find

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/

For functions you can add a docstring e.g.

```
def some_function():
  """ Write here a one line summary. 

If wanted, then leave a line and write a more detailed one"""
```

The `"""` need to be indented correctly to work

However, for hashes `#`, which is more common after single variables, they don't need to be indented correctly. E.g.

```
some_variable = Something  # This variable is doing this...
```

Hope that is somewhat helpful.

Comment: What if i need document the type of the variable?

Comment: When writing a inline comment remember to put at least two spaces in front of the `#`.

Comment: I think the following questions and answers will help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690220/how-to-document-python-function-parameter-types and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3051241/how-to-document-class-attributes-in-python

Answer (score 1):

PEP257 documents so called docstrings which is a string literal which appears as first statement in the definition of a module, class, function or a method. As far as I know if you want to leave some information about a variable you leave regular comments near it. For example:

```
# This is some variable ...
some_variable = ...
```

Answer (score -1):

You might find that people document **parameters**, what a function **returns**, and so on, but usually variables are not documented in python libraries.

The names should generally be self-explanatory.