# Python equivelent to PHPDoc Blocks?

Tags: php, python, python-3.x, docstring, docblocks

I am new to Python coming from PHP, I know Python has Docstrings, but how can I do this on class variables? Let's say in PHP I have:

```
class Animal {
    /**
     * @var Noise
    */
    public $noise
}
```

Now how would I implement this is python? Something like:

```
class Animal:
  # Here I want to tell my IDE that this is a noise object, not yet set
  self.noise = None
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898572/what-is-the-standard-python-docstring-format    I've been using three single quotes, my info, and three single quotes.

Comment: In this case, should I right a function like get_noise() that returns self.noise, and add the Docstring there?

Answer (score 2):

These are called "attribute docstrings." You can put the docstring after the declaration of the class, or in the `__init__` method:

From [PEP 257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/):

> String literals occurring immediately after a simple assignment at the
>   top level of a module, class, or **init** method are called "attribute
>   docstrings".

(see also [PEP 258](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0258/#attribute-docstrings)).

There are lots of resources on this, just search for "attribute docstrings," e.g., [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3051241/how-to-document-class-attributes-in-python).