# Python DocString (Google Style): How to document class attributes?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docstring, class-attributes

I have this small example:

```
"""Sandbox module"""

class Toto:
    """
    This class is an example

    Attributes:
        class_attribute (str): The class attribute #Unresolved reference
        instance_attribute (str): The instance attribute #OK
    """

    class_attribute = ""

    def __init__(self):
        self.instance_attribute = ""
        pass
```

This triggers an unresolved reference warning
How should I properly document the class attribute ?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you would like to use `napoleon` to render your docstrings into docs, the `sphinx` developers are working towards a way to add custom sections to class-level docstrings (see [Issue #33](https://github.com/sphinx-contrib/napoleon/issues/33)).

Currently, in the [Google Style Docstrings Example](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/example_google.html#example-google), the `class ExamplePEP526Class` example states

> If the class has public attributes, they may be documented here
> in an `Attributes` section and follow the same formatting as a
> function's `Args` section. If `napoleon_attr_annotations`
> is True, types can be specified in the class body using `PEP 526`
> annotations.

[PEP 526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/) added variable annotations to type hints. Hence, your code could now be written:

```py
"""Sandbox module"""

class Toto:
    """ This class is an example

    Attributes:
        class_attribute (str): (class attribute) The class attribute
        instance_attribute (str): The instance attribute
    """

    class_attribute: str = ""

    def __init__(self):
        self.instance_attribute: str = ""
```

For one thing, it seems you forgot to put the type hint `str` after `class_attribute` when defining it, so `mypy` (if using an external type checker) probably couldn't discover its type.

Ironically, the reverse situation would have worked: in `napoleon` version `3.4`, if `napoleon_attr_attributes` is set to `True`, then

> If an attribute is documented in the docstring without a type and has an annotation in the class body, that type is used.

Second, the `pass` at the end of your `__init__` method is allowed, but unnecessary since you define `instance_attribute` there.

I mention [Issue #33](https://github.com/sphinx-contrib/napoleon/issues/33) because, personally, I would rather call the heading "Class Variables" as "Attributes" by itself doesn't distinguish between instance vs. class attributes/variables. For the time being, you may want to put your own notation in the attribute description like I have done.

For me, I either have fewer class attributes than instance attributes or none at all, so I only note if an attribute is a class attribute (otherwise, it is an instance attribute). That way, I don't have to write `(instance attribute)` next to all my instance attributes. Alternatively, you could try putting `class` in the parentheses with the type the same what that `optional` is listed:

```py
class_attribute (str, class): The class attribute
```

I'm not sure if that will work or break. If it breaks, it would certainly be nice to have added to the docstring syntax in the future (I think this looks cleaner).

Lastly, you could document the class variable as an *attribute docstring* as defined in [PEP 257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring) as well as [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3051241/how-to-document-class-attributes-in-python) by putting a docstring directly underneath the assignment like so:

```py
"""Sandbox module"""

class Toto:

    class_attribute: str = ""
    """class_attribute (str): (class attribute) The class attribute"""

    def __init__(self):
        """ This class is an example
    
        Attributes:
            instance_attribute (str): The instance attribute
        """
        self.instance_attribute: str = ""
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```py
"""
    Sandbox module
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
"""

class Toto:
    """This class is an example

    Attributes:
        instance_attribute (str): The instance attribute #OK
    """
    
    #: str: The class attribute #Unresolved reference
    class_attribute = ""

    def __init__(self):
        self.instance_attribute = ""
        pass
```

This works fine for me using sphinx.

Comment: You haven't documented the class attribute though. You've just removed it from the class doc string.